# Method to call JavaScript AJAX function on page leave

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I have a web page with a form, a submit button for that form, and a link that takes a user to another page. I want to upload whatever changes I've made to that form to the server (a PHP script that will save the values) when a user clicks that link to take them to another page.

What is the best event to bind a JavaScript ajax function so that the form gets passed to the server and the user is then redirected to the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to redirect on the server side,
If using php:

```
header("Location: new_page.php"); //involves no javascript
```

Another way is to use javascript ajax, i use jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax(
    {
       url: this.action,
       data: $(this).serialize(),

       success: function(){
            window.location = 'newpage';//redirect on success
       }
    }
   )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind jQuery,

```
 $("#yourlink").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   });
location.href("your link"); //actually, i'm pretty sure the link will go ahead and fire anyways without this... 
    });
```